# How to add an external link to an image in img(src="")?

Tags: pug

I add product cards in a document product-list.pug  and adding an external link to url it isn`t rendered:

```
                each product in prods 
                .card 
                    h3 #{product.title}
                    p  
                        img(src='#{product.imageUrl}', alt="#{product.imageUrl}")
                    p #{product.price}
                    p #{product.description}
```

How to do that it would work? I add, for example, this link - "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.5SUhFpKmTir7RkmDLUqUXgAAAA%26pid%3DApi&f=1"

When it is rendered in HTML page, a html tag `<img>` is rendered like this: `<img src="#{product.imageUrl}">`, but should be `<img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.5SUhFpKmTir7RkmDLUqUXgAAAA%26pid%3DApi&f=1">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myImage = "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.5SUhFpKmTir7RkmDLUqUXgAAAA%26pid%3DApi&f=1"
img(src=myImage)
```

or in your case :

```
img(src=product.imageUrl)
```